If changes pushed to github mirror/push/clone the repository to my private server
I have a linux server in my priavte network at home and I want to be able to push changes from my windows pc to github (no Problem so far). But if I push the changes I want the changes made to the git repository on my private server as well.

I thought I can maybe achieve that via Github Actions.
